# How to use an animation tweening library on serverside on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tween

I try to use [es6-tween](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-tween) on Node.js. I want to calculate the tween and on update send them over Websocket to a client. (It is needed to be serverside)

```
let coords = { x: 0, y: 0 }; // Start at (0, 0)
let tween = await new Tween(coords)
        .to({ x: 100, y: 100 }, 1000)
        .on('update', ({x, y}) => {
            console.log(`The values is x: ${x} and y: ${y}`);
        })
        .start();
```

the update is never called. I don't have any errors. How could I use this on serverside? Also tried it with GASP or Tween.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
const { autoPlay, Tween } = TWEEN;
autoPlay(true);
```

and remove the `await`.

See this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/REwoMa?editors=1111).

Comment: worked! I forgot to do autoPlay(true); because I thought start() is doing that. is autoPlay() a global function? where is it coming from?